# How can I install older version (0.13.x) sbt on my MAC?

Tags: macos, scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I need sbt version 0.13.x for a course in Scala and I am having difficulties installing it. I tried with the `brew install sbt@0.13` command, but when I then check with `sbt about` it gives a message `No such file or directory`.

However, if I again try and do `brew install sbt@0.13`, it gives `Warning: sbt@0.13 0.13.16 is already installed`, although `sbt about` does not find anything.

In addition to that, I tried installing the latest version of sbt with `brew install sbt` and then manually changing the version each of my projects is using by entering `sbt.version=0.13.12` in a given `build.properties` file. This seemed to work initially, when I check with the terminal the version of sbt inside the project. However, I am still not able to import already existing projects.

Finally, I downloaded the version from http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html but then I need to do some corrections to my `PATH` from what I've read online and I am not sure what that means.
So, I would be grateful if someone could help me with the installation of an older version.

Comment: This might be helpful script https://github.com/prayagupd/programmer-mattress/blob/master/sbt.sh if your issue is getting sbt installed in macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `sbt` works is that it will look in `project/build.properties` for the `sbt` version to use to build your project. So the way you described - installing the latest `sbt` and set the version you want to use for the build in `project/build.properties` - should work just fine.
Regarding

> not able to import already existing projects

these existing projects also should have `project/build.properties` indicating the sbt version.

Note that even with installing 0.13.12 locally, when building your project `sbt` will still use the version specified in `project/build.properties`, it will just download it as necessary.

If you absolutely want to run a specific version from the command line, as you already discovered, you can download it. Regarding updating your `PATH` - `PATH` is an environment variable that tells your command line where to look for executable files. It's a list of directories, so if you unpacked the downloaded file in say "`$HOME/tools`", you have so say something like `export PATH=$HOME/tools/sbt/bin:$PATH`. See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/ for a more detailed description.

Comment: This clarifies lots of things for me. Now that you pointed it, I also noticed sbt is always using the specified in the build.properties file version. I even managed to import the project, but then Eclipse gives the “Could not find or load main class project.Main” error, so I guess I will be using IntelliJ for submissions after all. Still, learnt a lot about sbt and PATH. Very useful link too. Thank you!